# redireccion luego del alert de formulario con php

Tags: php, html5

hola tengo un formulario que cuando realiza la validacion acciona un alert ( o para informar que se envio o para pedir que se chequeen los datos) y al dar ACEPTAR en la ventana emergente, queda una pantalla en blanco que obliga al usuario a volver atras para regresar al formulario y de ahi (corregir el error o dirigirse a otra seccion) HORRIBLE!! jaja.

Como tendría que hacer (soy nueva en php y js) para que:
si es erroneo, vuelva al formulario asi el usuario chequea los datos y 
si es exitoso vuelva a la sección desde donde ingreso al formulario de contacto
paso el codigo

**HTML**

```
<div id="contact_form">
                <form action="confFormulario3.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
                    <input type="text" id="email" class="boton" name="email" placeholder="Tu email">
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" class="boton" name="nombre" placeholder="Cómo te llamas">
                    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" class="boton"  placeholder="En qué podemos ayudarte?"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="buttonEnviar" class="boton" value="ENVIAR">
                </form>
            </div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
 /*Capturamos las variables del POST con operadores ternarios*/
 $email=   filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
 $name=    ( empty($_POST["nombre"])    )  ?  NULL : $_POST["nombre"];
 $message= ( empty($_POST["mensaje"]) )  ?  NULL : $_POST["mensaje"];
 /*Verificamos que los tres datos fueron posteados*/
 if ($email && $name && $message){
   $para = 'timondigitalweb@gmail.com';
   $asunto = "mensaje de la web de el punto!!!!!!!!!!!!";
   $mailheader = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
   $mailheader .= "Reaply-To:".$email."\r\n";
   $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

   $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$name."\n";
   $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Email: ".$email."\n";
   $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Mensaje: ".nl2br($message)."\n";

   mail($para, $asunto, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("error al enviar mensaje, intente nuevamente");
   echo "<script>
            alert('Gracias por tu contacto! en breves nos estaremos comunicando 1');

        </script>";


 }else{
    //Aquí puedes también redirigir con un mensaje de error
    echo "<script>alert('Controla la informacion ingresada, el mensaje NO se ha enviado');</script>";
 }
 ?>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Recomendaría que usas Ajax para esto. Cuando aprendas a usarlo no  podrás separarte de él. Ajax te permite enviar cualquier información al servidor si tener que recargar la página, procesar esa información enviada y devolver una respuesta, la cual recuperas una vez terminada la petición, y en base a ella muestras un mensaje, cambias el contenido de la página o lo que sea. Todo de forma transparente y sin las horribles recargas de página, sólo al click de un botón o algo así. Aquí hay varias respuestas que explican cómo funciona Ajax.

Comment: Todo un  sueño! jaja. Lo voy a apuntar en mi lista de cosas por aprender a corto plazo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puedes hacer lo siguiente en el mismo codigo que tienes
 echo "<script>
            alert('Gracias por tu contacto! en breves nos estaremos comunicando 1');
                    window.location='index.php?page=otrapagina'
                  </script>";
```

Comment: gracias por el aporte! Tenes idea de como solucionar que cuando algo esta mal completado, que no se abra el alert en una pagina en blanco? así no tiene que volver atrás el usuario

Comment: Al ejecutarse el alert debe enviar al usuario a la pagina que le indique en window.location=" aqui colocas la url de la pagina"

Comment: hernadez probé el código y no direcciona a la pagina ni muestra el alert??? algo debe faltar...

Comment: muestra el codigo como lo estas colocando por favor

Comment: probé: `alert('Gracias por tu contacto! en breves nos estaremos comunicando 2');   window.location="www.timondigital.com/web"` también `window.location="index.php"` y `window.location="index.php?contacto.php"` y con ninguno muestra el alert... y menos redirigir. Gracias por chequear cual es el error

Comment: echo '<script>
          alert("Gracias por tu contacto! en breves nos estaremos comunicando 1");
                    window.location="index.php"
                  </script>';

con esto te debe funcionar. pasa que estas utilizando comillas simples y dobles si el echo comienza con comillas simples echo '  '; todo lo que esta dentro y tenga comillas deben estar con comillas dobles y viceversa echo " ";

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias!